# What is `antialiased` in `matplotlib.collections` and how do you set the parameter for it?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

What is `antialiased` in `matplotlib.collections` and how do you set the parameter for it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `antialiased` keyword argument controls whether or not a particular matplotlib artist (e.g. line, polygon, etc) is [drawn with antialising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing) or not.

As an example, notice the difference in the two plots below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(range(10), antialiased=False)
plt.title('Antialiasing Off')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(range(10), antialiased=True)
plt.title('Antialiasing On')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Non-antialiased plotting will be faster, so if you're plotting a large amount of data, it can be worthwhile to turn it off.