# Description of arguments in surface plot function in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface

Hi I am writing a code which uses `ax.plot_surface()` to plot data on a unit sphere for `theta = linspace(0,pi,100)` and `phi = linspace(0,2*pi,100)`.

For some reason my image is distorted in the sense that the sphere is ahead of the axis. Does anyone have any idea of why this would be the case?

Comment: could downvoters explain to help improve the qu? Although it could include example code to produce a specific problem, a quick look at the docs do not immediately explain any of the arguments asked about. So the question has merit, no?

Comment: The problem with this question is that it asks about parameters which are irrelevant to the problem. Either ask about the parameters (and be happy with the answer to it) or ask about the specific problem you have..

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited the question now in line with your suggestion.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091229/trim-data-outside-3d-plot-in-matplotlib).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't think it's data outlier problem. It's just a visual perspective problem. Do you know how to by default display the set of axis in front of the graph?

Comment: As I see it, it is exactly the same problem. The data is shown outside the axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3D plotting isn't necessarily a good place to start learning how to use plotting libraries; the fundamentals are more often explained in simpler 2d plots.  But to get started,

- read the [3d tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)
- use the [3d examples](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#mplot3d-toolkit) for reference
- experiment! Produce the same figure with different parameter settings.

The specific parameters you asked about:

- **linewidth** is not relevant for the [`plot_surface`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html?highlight=plot_surface#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface), but does make a big difference in the closely related [`plot_wireframe`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html?highlight=plot_wireframe#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_wireframe). See [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/subplot3d_demo.html) and experiment with the linewidth value. 1 is default.
- **alpha** refers to transparency, of a graphical element. Any value <1 will mean it is possible to see other lines etc, even directly behind. [This example uses alpha=0.3 in 3d](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/contourf3d_2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-contourf3d-2-py)
- **antialiased** controls whether the rendering is done with anti-aliasing or not.  It is more expensive to use, but the result is to reduce visual distortions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750463 which also links [this explanation of the method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing).