# How to force matplotlib to write specific RGB values in each pixel in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have code that generates images with filled circles, that can be one of 10 colors using `plt.fill`, with the X and Y coordinates of one `circle` at a time from `circle_list`:

```py
for i in range(0, R.shape[0]):
   radius = R[i]
   circle = circle_list[i]
   color = assigned_colors[i]
   plt.fill(circle[:, 0], circle[:, 1], facecolor=color)
```

`assigned_colors` is a list of the same length as `R.shape[0]` (the total number of circles to draw) with one of the colors specified in `color_list`:

```py
color_list = [(.14,.33,.49), (.08,.41,.27), (.37,.76,.35), (.92,.58,.13),
              (.90,.25,.09), (.96,.75,.12), (.74,.09,.15), (.80,.76,.56), 
              (.56,.70,.72), (.77,.71,.76)]
```

I then save this image as a numpy ndarray:

```py
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=350)
arr = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
arr = arr.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
np.save('arr.npy', arr)
```

This all works great, but I would for some analysis I do, I would like to use the unique RGB values specified for filling the circles as unique IDs. However, when I load the array, and look at the unique colors, I observe *many* more than expected:

```py
circles_npy = np.load('./arr.npy')
len(np.unique(circles_npy.reshape(-1, circles_npy.shape[2]), axis=0))

>>> 2854
```

If I draw the image, it visually looks like the 10 colors I specified are drawn, but why are the RGB values so different? Is there a way to force matplotlib to only use those *exact* values, plus a background color? I would have expected this to return 11 (for the 10 possible colors plus the white background. I don't understand what's going on here and how can I use colors as labels in the array? Ideally what I am looking for is a unique value for every color in the image array.

Comment: I suspect it's anti aliasing https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750463/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes! Thanks! I had no idea this was a thing that matplotlib did.